# Eclipse issue When I exit Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-plugin

My Eclipse not working when I build project in Tomcat server.When I exit the Eclipse the following   message give Eclipse.

I have no idea about Eclipse.

Can anyone tell me how can I  resolve this issue ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a problem in settings `eclipse.ini` file. 

Try this settings. May be it helps.

```
-vmargs
-Xincgc
-Xss500k
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms64m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:NewSize=8m
-XX:PermSize=80m
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
-XX:MaxPermHeapExpansion=10m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+CMSConcurrentMTEnabled
-XX:ConcGCThreads=2
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=2
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0
-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycle=5
-XX:GCTimeRatio=49
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20
-XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=1000
-XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrentAndUnloadsClasses
```